# R: covert .log to .xml file

Tags: r, xml, logging, telemetry

I have a .log file (Telemetry data) which is basically a xml file. The data is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1"> <ns2:PartnerVehicles> <ns2:PartnerVehicle> <ns2:partnerNotificationID>080298234</ns2:partnerNotificationID> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="EventBased"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Location"> <ns2:VehicleDataList> <ns2:vehicleDataDetails>Timestamp Latitude Longitude Speed Direction IsIgnOff IgnitionStateChange</ns2:vehicleDataDetails> <ns2:vehicleData> <ns2:telemetryData> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:50:12.000Z 35.2386818 -80.9514771 N/A N/A N/A N/A</ns2:telemetry> </ns2:telemetryData> </ns2:vehicleData> </ns2:VehicleDataList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="TripHBHA"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Diagnostic"> <ns2:DataElementList> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>PARK_NEUTRAL_CHECK</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>NOT_PARK</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:12.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>75488.53125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:12.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel Capacity</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>49.125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:12.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel amount</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>29.475</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>NOTIFICATION_ID</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>T519154342260102_1212_1</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>N/A</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> </ns2:DataElementList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> </ns2:PartnerVehicle> </ns2:PartnerVehicles> </PostTelemetryRequest><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1"> <ns2:PartnerVehicles> <ns2:PartnerVehicle> <ns2:partnerNotificationID>086421226</ns2:partnerNotificationID> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="EventBased"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Location"> <ns2:VehicleDataList> <ns2:vehicleDataDetails>Timestamp Latitude Longitude Speed Direction IsIgnOff IgnitionStateChange</ns2:vehicleDataDetails> <ns2:vehicleData> <ns2:telemetryData> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:49:11.000Z 42.3370323 -83.0454407 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:49:42.000Z 42.3370323 -83.0454407 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z 42.3370323 -83.0454407 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:50:44.000Z 42.3370323 -83.0454407 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> </ns2:telemetryData> </ns2:vehicleData> </ns2:VehicleDataList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="TripHBHA"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Diagnostic"> <ns2:DataElementList> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>31261.828125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:11.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_RSSI</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>MAX</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:13.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_SERVICE</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>4G_LTE</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:13.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>31261.828125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_RSSI</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>MAX</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:44.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_SERVICE</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>4G_LTE</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:44.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>31261.828125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:13.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_RSSI</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>MAX</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:15.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_SERVICE</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>4G_LTE</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:15.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Oil life</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>56.862765</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>%</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>31261.828125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure LF</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>220</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure RF</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>220</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure LR</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>216</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure RR</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>216</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel Capacity</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>118.375</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:43.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_RSSI</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>MAX</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:44.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_SERVICE</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>4G_LTE</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:44.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>31261.828125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:44.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_RSSI</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>MAX</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:46.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>CELL_SERVICE</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>4G_LTE</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>NA</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:46.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel amount</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>33.85525</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>NOTIFICATION_ID</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>T751204345198168_1211_1</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>N/A</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> </ns2:DataElementList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> </ns2:PartnerVehicle> </ns2:PartnerVehicles> </PostTelemetryRequest>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1"> <ns2:PartnerVehicles> <ns2:PartnerVehicle> <ns2:partnerNotificationID>080595911</ns2:partnerNotificationID> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="EventBased"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Location"> <ns2:VehicleDataList> <ns2:vehicleDataDetails>Timestamp Latitude Longitude Speed Direction IsIgnOff IgnitionStateChange</ns2:vehicleDataDetails> <ns2:vehicleData> <ns2:telemetryData> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:48:51.000Z 38.7962875 -104.6996994 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:49:22.000Z 38.7962875 -104.6996994 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:49:53.000Z 38.7962875 -104.6996994 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> <ns2:telemetry>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z 38.7962875 -104.6996994 N/A N/A N N</ns2:telemetry> </ns2:telemetryData> </ns2:vehicleData> </ns2:VehicleDataList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="TripHBHA"/> <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Diagnostic"> <ns2:DataElementList> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>36333.3125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:48:51.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>36333.3125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:22.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>36333.3125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:49:53.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>36333.3125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:24.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Oil life</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>88.235325</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>%</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>ODO_READ</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>36333.3125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KM</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure LF</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>228</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure RF</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>220</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure LR</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>220</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Tire Pressure RR</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>224</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>KPa</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel Capacity</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>49.125</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>2018-02-12T13:50:42.000Z</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>Fuel amount</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>38.514</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>L</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> <ns2:DataElement> <ns2:Name>NOTIFICATION_ID</ns2:Name> <ns2:Value>T751204345033629_1211_1</ns2:Value> <ns2:UOM>N/A</ns2:UOM> <ns2:Timestamp>N/A</ns2:Timestamp> </ns2:DataElement> </ns2:DataElementList> </ns2:TelemetryDataDetails> </ns2:PartnerVehicle> </ns2:PartnerVehicles> </PostTelemetryRequest>
...
```

In order for R to read the .xml file, first I need to convert the .log file to .xml. The output I'm looking for is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PostTelemetryRequest
   xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1">
   <ns2:PartnerVehicles>
       <ns2:PartnerVehicle>
            <ns2:partnerNotificationID>080298234</ns2:partnerNotificationID>
            <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="EventBased"/>
            <ns2:TelemetryDataDetails Type="Location">
...
```

I'm somehow able to read the .xml file in R but not able to convert the .log file to .xml in r. The other option I tried is to copy the contents of .log & change to .xml in one of the websites designed for that purpose but I want the r code to do the work since I need to read a huge no. of files.

Comment: If all that content is in one document, that is a not a well-formed XML file as the [XML declaration by W3C rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) states it may appear once or not at all as the first line. DOM libraries including R ones that follow W3C standards should correctly fail to parse such a document due to its non well-formedness.

Comment: Now each line appears to be XML markup. So, you can read each line into R like a text file and then output as separate XML files. However, you do not explain how each line contributes to what seems to be **one** XML output.